# 2D projection of constant energy contour in momentum space in 2DEG heterostructures or 2D layered materials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

When reading about 2D layered materials or 2DEG (two dimensional electron gas) heterostructures , there often is a 2D projection of a constant energy contour onto the plane perpendicular to the confinement direction.

For example, in fig 1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.05032.pdf), it talks about
projection of the constant energy ellipsoids in the 3D momentum space being projected onto the 2D surface ($k_x$ and $k_y$) perpendicular to the $(001)$ Si surface.

Is such a projection considered informative because it helps us examine different effective masses based on surface orientations, among other reasons?

I believe the 2D confinement of the heterostructure makes Z the quantization direction. So, $E_{n,z}$ is discreet and it's this confinement that lifts the $\pm Z$ valley degeneracies.

In general, when does it make sense to take a 3D constant energy contour in the crystal momentum space and do a 2D projection?